# How can I access a column name within a function in a mutate call?

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr, rlang

I am mutating a column to create a new one in R using a function I wrote.

Within my function, I want to send a message that includes the name of the column that is being changed.

How can I access the column name that is being mutated from inside of the function within the mutate call?

Reproducible Example:

```
data <- tribble(
 ~colB, 
  1, 
  2, 
  3
)

# Function that will be used in the mutate
add1 <- function(numeric_vector) {
  return(1 +numeric_vector)

  # I want to message the user the name of the column they are mutating
  # This simply returns the entire vector
  message("You mutated", numeric vector)

  # This returns 'numeric_vector'
  message("You mutated", quo_name(quo(numeric_vector)))

}

# Desired Output:
data %>% 
  mutate(colC = add1(colB))

You mutated colB
 colB  colC
 <dbl> <dbl>
   1     2
   2     3
   3     4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `substitute` which returns a `name` class object.  We have wrapped the `message` call in an `on.exit` to ensure that it is run *after* the calculation so that it is not run if the calculation fails.  If that is not important then replace `on.exit(message(...))` with just `message(...)`.  Note that `add1` itself does not use any packages.

```
library(dplyr)

add1 <- function(numeric_vector) {
  on.exit(message("You mutated ", substitute(numeric_vector)))
  1 + numeric_vector
}

BOD %>% mutate(Time = add1(Time))
```

giving:

```
You mutated Time
  Time demand
1    2    8.3
2    3   10.3
3    4   19.0
4    5   16.0
5    6   15.6
6    8   19.8
```

### rlang

To use rlang make use of `enexpr` from that package.  dplyr will make it available. `enexpr` returns a `name` class object.

`enexpr` is similar to `substitute` but one difference that will affect processing is that  `substitute` will extract the code portion of a promise whether or not the promise has been forced (i.e. evaluated); however, `enexpr` will extract the code of unforced promises  but will extract the value of forced promises.  Since we want the code portion we must ensure that `enexpr(numeric_vector)` is run *before* `numeric_vector` is used in a calculation.  To ensure that we introduce a new variable `arg_name` which is run at the beginning ensuring that `enexpr` has an unforced argument.

```
library(dplyr)

add2 <- function(numeric_vector) {
  arg_name <- enexpr(numeric_vector)
  on.exit(message("You mutated ", arg_name))
  1 + numeric_vector
}

BOD %>% mutate(Time = add2(Time))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
add1 <- function(numeric_vector) {
  message(paste("You mutated", quo_name(enquo(numeric_vector))))
  return(1 + numeric_vector)
}
```

Note that you have to print your message before the `return()`. Nothing after the `return()` will run in a function because you exit when you hit that statement. Also, you can use `enquo()` to grab the variable to get it's name. And you need to get it's name while it's still in a promise state, so that means before you actually use it's value.